# How to install tensorflow_hub with anaconda (windows)

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow-hub

after having installed apparently correctly the tensorflow-hub package through the Anaconda navigator (Anaconda version 4.10.1), I've tried to import in a jupyter labs notebook, but it appears the following error mesage:

*ImportError: cannot import name 'parameter_server_strategy_v2' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute' (E:...\Anaconda_software\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute_*init*_.py)*

Then I've tried to install through Anaconda prompt and.. no problem with that but.. trying yo import.. It appears the same error message. Any ideas to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please have a look at this similar issue. https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/753

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've checked that Github comment and the problem I have is that I'm trying to upgrade from tensorflow 2.3 to (I guess) 2.4, but Anaconda does..nothing. I mean, I see this:

Comment: Sorry,  my comment was cut.  Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've checked that Github comment and the problem I have is that I'm trying to upgrade from tensorflow 2.3 to (I guess) 2.4, but Anaconda does..nothing. I've just asked that before read your answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121169/problems-to-upgrade-tensorflow-with-anaconda-on-windows-10 ), but the problem rigth now I suppose is the upgrading. Then I'll check if that fix this.

Comment: BAD NEWS!!: I've tried to install tensorflow 2.4.0 from anaconda prompt instead of doing with  Navigator and... apparently it worked. When I executed the import tensofrlow_hub on my notebook It worked OK but... The model.fit method shows an error!!:   "No found  error: No algorithm worked!.   [[node sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at <ipython-input-56-538f10686e58>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1757]
Function call stack:
train_function"

Comment: Ok! Glad It helped. Please open a separate Stackoverflow question for that with  description ,Code snippet and Error stack trace .  you can find the Stackoverflow guideline here.    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask