# Problems to upgrade tensorflow with Anaconda on Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

.
Hello all,
I'm using Anaconda 2.0.3 on Windows 10 and it detects that a possible upgrade for tensorflow library so... I marked it to uograde and click on apply but... nothing happens. Any idea ?

[Anaconda screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y7T9.png)

Thanks

Comment: Is your issue resolved now?else can you try to upgrade using conda prompt as `pip install --user tensorflow --upgrade`.

Comment: Hi, I tried that weeks ago and it worked, but, the question was in relation abut the navigator. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: That's good to hear. For quick support on anaconda navigator, please post it [here](https://groups.google.com/a/anaconda.com/g/anaconda). Thanks!